# Can't access custom color from Tailwind CSS configuration using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I am trying to access a custom color in my Next.js project. Here is my `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'custom-green': 'rgb(30,214,97)',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        figtree: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require('tailwind-scrollbar-hide')],
};
```

I am trying to access this color in one of my React components, `components/Accordion.tsx`, since I cannot style the MUI components directly with the `className` prop. Here is how I am accessing it:

```js
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
import tailwindConfig from '../tailwind.config.js';

...

const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);
console.log(fullConfig);
fullConfig.theme.extend.colors['custom-green'],    // ERROR HERE
```

This is the error I get in browser and the terminal:

> Server Error
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Also, when inspecting the config that I printed out in the console there is no `extend` property under the `theme` object. What am I doing wrong here? I followed these tutorials, but still can't get it to work:

- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script
- https://www.javascriptguides.com/how-to-access-tailwind-css-colors-from-javascript/

However, when I use the following code, it works fine but there are red warnings in VSCode:

```js
fullConfig.theme.colors['custom-green']
```

This is the VSCode error I get even though it works fine in the browser:

> Property 'colors' does not exist on type 'UnwrapResolvables<{ extend: { colors: { 'spotify-green': string; 'spotify-main-bg': string; 'spotify-main-unselected': string; 'spotify-side-unselected': string; 'spotify-profile-bg': string; 'spotify-card-bg': string; 'spotify-card-hover': string; }; fontFamily: { ...; }; }; }>'.ts(2339) any`

Is it my configuration file? Do I need to change the type at the top to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are extending the colors from the config, why not just export a object with your custom colors and use the same object in your config? instead of trying to read the value? Assuming you need to do it for whatever reason. looks like a typing issue, you can try tailwind 3.3 which adds ts support.

Comment: According to the second article you reference above, `fullConfig.theme.colors['custom-green']` is the correct way to reference your value. I'm not sure about the VSCode error.